# How to make a list from a raw_input in python?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, raw-input

So I am taking `raw_input` as an input for some list.

```
x= raw_input()
```

Where I input `1 2 3 4`
How will I convert it into a list of integers if I am inputting only numbers?

Comment: `map(int, raw_input.split())`

Comment: @StevenRumbalski `map(int, raw_input().split())` ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Like this:

```
string_input = raw_input()
input_list = string_input.split() #splits the input string on spaces
# process string elements in the list and make them integers
input_list = [int(a) for a in input_list]
```

Comment: @user3481478 You can accept the answer you find most useful.

Comment: Also, say you want to specify the length of the list, say 4 and take only 4 inputs into your list, this should help : `input_arr = []` `while len(input_arr) < 4:
 input_arr.append(raw_input("enter test arrays:\t"))`

Answer (score 10):

`list = map(int,raw_input().split())`

We are using a higher order function `map` to get a list of `integers`.

Comment: this works only for numbers or integers, but a list may also have combined datatypes as elements!!!!
viz: list_new=['aaa','bbb',23,45,'ccc']
in such a case how do we split them when read as string...

Comment: You substitute 'int' with the required datatype.

Comment: i have a mixed datatype as u can see in the above comment.....hence i can't substitute any static value over there....

Comment: A custom function can usually be written for specific cases. I think it would be better if you post this as a separate question

Comment: posted a separate question....thnx for the encouragement @perseus....
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43822895/how-to-separate-a-mixed-datatype-string-taken-as-input-into-list

Answer (score 3):

You can do the following using [`eval`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval):

```
lst = raw_input('Enter your list: ')
lst = eval(lst)
print lst
```

This runs as:

```
>>> lst = raw_input('Enter your list: ')
Enter your list: [1, 5, 2, 4]
>>> lst = eval(lst)
>>> print lst
[1, 5, 2, 4]
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are some examples and brief explanation for Inputting Lists from users:

You may often need code that reads data from the console into a list. You can enter one data
item per line and append it to a list in a loop. For example, the following code reads ten numbers one per line into a list.

```
lst1 = [] # Create an empty list
print("Enter 10 Numbers: ")
for i in range(10):
   lst1.append(eval(input()))

print(lst1)
```

Sometimes it is more convenient to enter the data in one line separated by spaces. You can
use the string’s split method to extract data from a line of input. For example, the following
code reads ten numbers separated by spaces from one line into a list.

```
# Read numbers as a string from the console
s = input("Enter 10 numbers separated by spaces from one line: ")
items = s.split() # Extract items from the string
lst2 = [eval(x) for x in items] # Convert items to numbers

print(lst2)
```

Invoking `input()` reads a string. Using `s.split()` extracts the items delimited by
spaces from string `s` and returns items in a list. The last line creates a list of numbers by converting the items into numbers.

Comment: maybe include the link where you found this text and the examples?

Comment: Introduction to Programming Using Python
by Y. Daniel Liang page 313