# how to separate a mixed datatype string taken as input into list

Tags: python, list

Consider the below code,

```
string_new=raw_input('Enter data')
```

The input supplied was:

'aaa' 'bbb' 23 21 56 98 'ccc'

Each of the above values were space seperated

We require this to be converted to list:

```
list=['aaa','bbb',23,21,56,98,'ccc']
```

I tried previous solutions as given on
[Get a list of numbers as input from the user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4663306/get-a-list-of-numbers-as-input-from-the-user/4663342?noredirect=1#comment74683875_4663342)

and 
[How to make a list from a raw_input in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23026324/how-to-make-a-list-from-a-raw-input-in-python/36019858?noredirect=1#comment74683789_36019858)

using

```
map(int,string_new.split())
```

However that works only for integers and we have different datatypes elements passed as an input and separated by space.

Any suggestions...

Comment: _our string is carrying mixed datatype_ Well not really - a string is a string, even if it contains digits.

Answer (score 3):

Raw input converts the input from the user into a string. The following will produce a list that is split on spaces as you are requesting.

```
string_new = raw_input('Enter data')
input_list = string_new.split()
```

If you wish to convert integer-likes within the input_list:

```
mix_list = []
for in_string in input_list:
    try:
        mix_list.append(int(in_string))
    except:
        mix_list.append(in_string)
```

Comment: @FarhanPatel well `raw_input` gives you a string, and `split()` will only work on strings.

Comment: @patrick, however that's not the output which is desired!!!....
split would result in [' "aaa" ', ' "bbb" ', '23','21'.....

Comment: @BryceFrank, hey buddy pls run the edited answer in any of the python ide, u would see the if it's not a integer it results in [' "aaa" ', ' "bbb" '].....where in it becomes string of string.....

Comment: also, i hv suggested edit for string_new and string_input variable mismatch!!!...@BryceFrank pls verify!!